# Condition is not working as expected in KendoUI Column Template

Tags: javascript, java, kendo-grid

I'm getting JSON data through an API and displaying it in a table using Kendo UI.

```js
$scope.ReportViewGrid = function ReportViewGrid(jsonData) {
  if (jsonData == null) return;

  var fileName = "ReportView";
  var grid = $("#ReportViewGrid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: [{
      template: "<input type='button' class='k-button' value='Back' onclick='back()' />"
    }],
    editable: false,
    filterable: true,
    resizable: true,
    pageable: {
      pageSize: 10,
      buttonCount: 5
    },
    columns: jsonData.columns,
    dataSource: {
      data: jsonData.children
    },

  }).data("kendoGrid");
}
```

```html
<div id="ReportViewGrid"></div>
```

Above code shows data perfectly. There are multiple columns in the grid as follows:

```
-----------------
C1 | C2 | C3 | C4
-----------------
v1 | v2 | v3 | v4
x1 | x2 | x3 |
y1 | y2 | y3 |
z1 | z2 | z3 | z4
```

Column1 is made linked using template. But I want to get linked data where I'm having value in column4 otherwise normal text. I've tried the following code and tried flipping the condition as well but the links are always coming up.

```
...
 if("uName".equalsIgnoreCase(uNameField)){
    template = "#  if (\"#=encodeURI(md5hash)#\".equals(\"\") ) { #"
                    +" <span>#=fileName#</span>"
                    +" # } else{ #"
                    +" <a style=\"cursor: pointer;\" onclick='expand(\"fileDetailForDuplicateFile\",\"#=encodeURI(fileName)#\",\"#=encodeURI(md5hash)#\")'>#=fileName#</a>"
                    +" #} #";
     nodeColumns.setTemplate(template);
 }
 root.addColumns(nodeColumns);
 }
 root.addLinkedColumn("uName");
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 return gson.toJson(root);
```

Is there anything that I'm missing? Any help will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this useful to do checks inside the template using data.xx, like this:-

```
template = "# if(data.md5hash == ''){ #" +
" <span>#=fileName#</span> " +
" #} else {#" +
" <a style=\"cursor: pointer;\" onclick='expand(\"fileDetailForDuplicateFile\",\"#=encodeURI(fileName)#\",\"#=encodeURI(md5hash)#\")'>#=fileName#</a>" +
" # } #";
```